# Django: other options than models.TextField() for articles

Tags: python, django

So in the [Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) we make a sparse polls application that shows off some of what Django can do, but leaves a lot to be desired when it comes to learning Django (e.g. using their `UserCreationForm` to make a user portal).

In part of the tutorial they talk about how the `admin` should be publishing content (e.g. if it were a blog or newspaper) and we set up the admin site where one can make new questions for the polls.

In regard to the blog idea - since an article would be lengthy most likely - I think the correct model would include `models.TextField`. However, looking at Django's naturally generated admin site for adding / modifying new models with a `TextField` leaves a lot to be desired.

What if there should be images embedded among the text? or what if there should be formatted text? The admin site does not support a user friendly way to do this.

My question is how to produce a user friendly way for making mixed media e.g. a Stack Exchange post which might have images, code formatting, text formats, etc.

Comment: This is all a bit vague. Are you asking about how to use a WYSIWYG widget? There are plenty of libraries that will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**Django Pagedown**](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown) which aims exactly to offer a way of editing similar to that found on stackexchange sites. As for now you cannot yet upload images (this feature is though on the todos list of the author), they must be  already uploaded somewhere on the web and you can insert them using their url.